# How to reduce commit memory for vc++ application?

Tags: visual-c++, memory, optimization, memory-leaks, commit

I have an application written in vc++. When the application runs, i can observer (in windows resource monitor) the commit memory for my application to be very high where as private memory to be approximately half of it. Can someone please suggest how can i lower down the commit memory for my application. Will removing dead/junk code and unused variable help ?
Any help in this regard is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually that means you are creating lots of objects and not deleting them. Look for where you use `new`.